# Как соединить переменную с переменной

Tags: python, переменные

Не знаю как соединить 2 переменные по типу a+b

```
count = 0

for i in range(10):
    count += 1
    a_ = "text"
    
    print(a_ count) # как то так
```

Должно быть что-то по типу вывода `Hello_3`

Полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from __Task__ import *
from __data__ import Count

root = Tk()

def add_Task(size, reg, ins):
    root2 = Tk()

    def added(arg):
        count = Count
        count += 1
        with open("__data__.py", "w") as f:
            f.write(f"Count = {count}")
        with open("__Task__.py", "a") as f:
            f.write(f'Task_{count} = "{addTask.get()}"\n')

        Label(text=Task_[count]).pack()

    root2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", Quit)
    root2.geometry("+200+300")

    addTask = Entry(root2, font=f"Arial {size} {reg}", insertbackground=ins)
    addTask.pack()
    addTask.bind("<Return>", added)

def Quit():
    quit()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", Quit)
root.overrideredirect(0)
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)

Button(text="Add", command=lambda: add_Task(20, "bold", "red")).pack(fill=BOTH)

Label(text=Task_1).pack(fill=BOTH)
Label(text=Task_1).pack(fill=BOTH)
Label(text=Task_1).pack(fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `a + str(b)` . .

Comment: Да нет я немного не про это

Comment: а про что?.....

Comment: Вы хотите получить переменную `Hello_3`?

Comment: В новом вопросе всё то же самое: `a_ + str(count)`

Comment: Да и вообще переменная `count` здесь бессмысленная, потому что её значение будет всегда равно `i + 1`

Comment: В моем коде count обьязательна

Comment: Новый код мы видим, а что нужно, всё равно непонятно. Судя по коду, вы пытаетесь генерировать новый Python-код на лету, а это очень плохая идея примерно всегда. Вообще, возникает ощущение, что вы в учебнике по питону пропустили главу про списки и все проблемы у вас от незнания списков

Comment: Собственно, квадратные скобочки `Task_[count]` это уже готовый синтаксис для получения элемента списка, если бы существовал список `Task_`

Answer (score 0):

Существуют f строки
Пример:

```
a = 5
b = "Котов"
print(f"{a}_{b}" # 5_Котов
print(f"{a} {b}" # 5 Котов
```

Comment: Мне такой вариант же уже предлогали

Comment: Ну так значит отметь как решение